# Excel Download Not working in Server/Site but working in Local System

Tags: .net, excel

We have a site, in  that we have a option to download excel report, recently we have migrated(using VS 2010) and from `.net 2.0` to `4.0` and the hosted server also changed. server same as previous server which is 2003 and MS Excel installed in it. The same code working fine in my local system(XP, VS-2010). When I click the button to download excel, I'm getting the following error.

> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

I followed the instruction here http://forums.asp.net/p/1303594/3359738.aspx#3359738. after that it worked fine. But again the same error occurs. We have used `Interope.Excel` dll in project.

Please tell me the solution if you know. Thanks.

Comment: I think, your error depends on your coding language, for more helps please add its tag and your code to your question.